# jquery click on link have style applied to the link and also show an element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the codepen: http://codepen.io/tristananthonymyers/full/BRPmKa/

I am trying to get when a link is clicked the ".active-link:after" style is applied to which ever link is clicked and the corresponding page like "#about-page" shows. The problem is the "#about-page" only shows and all the links get ".active-link:after" style applied to them.

I'm not that experienced with Jquery but I feel like I mostly know what I'm doing when it comes to HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
 <p class="placeholder-logo logo">Tristan Myers</p>
 <p class="placeholder-logo-text logo">Front-end Web Developer/Designer</p>
</div>
<div class="nav-links"> 
 <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="about-link">About Me</a>
 <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="work-link">My Work</a>
 <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="contact-link">Contact Me</a></div>
<div class="page" id="about-page">
 <p>this is about page.</p>
</div>
<div class="page" id="work-page">
 <p>this is work page.</p>
</div>
<div class="page" id="contact-page">
 <p>this is contact page.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show {
  visibility: visible; 
 }  
.active-link:after {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
var navLink = $('.nav-link')
var aboutLink = $('#about-link');
var workLink = $('#work-link');
var contactLink = $('#contact-link');
var aboutPage = $('#about-page');
var workPage = $('#work-page');
var contactPage = $('#contact-page');

navLink.click(function togglePage(about, work, contact) {
 toggleAboutPage(about);
 toggleWorkPage(work);
 toggleContactPage(contact);
 return false;
});

function toggleAboutPage() {
 aboutPage.toggleClass('show');
 aboutLink.toggleClass('active-link');
};

function toggleWorkPage() {
 workPage.toggleClass('show');
 workLink.toggleClass('active-link');
};

function toggleContactPage() {
 contactPage.toggleClass('show');
 contactLink.toggleClass('active-link');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(){
  var index = $(".nav-link").index($(this));

  $(".nav-link").removeClass("active-link");
  $(this).addClass("active-link");

  $(".page").removeClass("show");
  $($(".page").get(index)).addClass("show");
});
```

[Here is the **CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKmRKm)

Comment: This is closer to what I'm trying to get to with this but the pages for the work and contact links are not showing. What would I do to add those?

Comment: This is probably based on how you styled your page. Please check your CSS.